# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower' when applying Global MaxPooling instead of GlobalAveragePooling

Tags: python, keras, error-handling

This are my imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Input, Reshape, Concatenate, GlobalAveragePooling2D, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Activation, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import Sequence
import efficientnet.keras as efn
```

I then created the following model:

```
efnB0_model = efn.EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
efnB0_model.trainable = False

def create_model(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = efnB0_model (input_img)
    #model = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(model)
    model = GlobalMaxPooling2D(model)
    model = Dropout(0.2)(model)
    backbone = model

    branches = []
    for i in range(7):
            branches.append(backbone)
            branches[i] = Dense(360, name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
            branches[i] = BatchNormalization()(branches[i])
            branches[i] = Activation("relu") (branches[i])
            branches[i] = Dropout(0.2)(branches[i])           
            branches[i] = Dense(35, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])
        
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
    output = Reshape((7, 35))(output)
    model = Model(input_img, output)

    return model
```

When I use `GlobaleAveragePooling2D` (which is commented out in the code upon) and run `model = create_model()` everything works just fine. When I instead use `GlobalMaxPooling2D` and run `model = create_model()` I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-834f03506210> in <module>()
----> 1 model = create_model()

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in normalize_data_format(value)
    309     if value is None:
    310         value = image_data_format()
--> 311     data_format = value.lower()
    312     if data_format not in {'channels_first', 'channels_last'}:
    313         raise ValueError('The `data_format` argument must be one of '

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower
```

How should I modify my code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: have u tried GlobalAveragePooling2D()(model.output) ?

Comment: Thanks but no, because I do not have a problem with the GlobalAveragePooling2D but with GlobalMaxPooling2D. What could it reveal to use this?

Comment: sorry... it's GlobalMaxPooling2D()(model.output)... GlobalAveragePooling2D must be commented/deleted (use only one of them)

Comment: Oh man, yes, solved.. `model = GlobalMaxPooling2D() (model)` works. The () were missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses `()` are missing. `model = GlobalMaxPooling2D() (model)`works for me.

So, this is the solution:

```
def create_model(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = efnB0_model (input_img)
    #model = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(model)
    model = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(model)
    model = Dropout(0.2)(model)
    backbone = model

    branches = []
    for i in range(7):
            branches.append(backbone)
            branches[i] = Dense(360, name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
            branches[i] = BatchNormalization()(branches[i])
            branches[i] = Activation("relu") (branches[i])
            branches[i] = Dropout(0.2)(branches[i])           
            branches[i] = Dense(35, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])
        
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
    output = Reshape((7, 35))(output)
    model = Model(input_img, output)

    return model
```